# Test class for Abstract class with no default constructor and private method?

Tags: java, junit4, easymock, testcase

I have got a problem in my project and I'm putting up my problem in some sample example.

```
package com.sample.code;

public abstract class AbstractClass {

    public String var1;

    //in this class NO default constructor

    public String method1(){
        return "method1 "+privateMethod();
    }

    protected AbstractClass(String var1){
        this.var1=var1;
    }

    private String privateMethod(){
        return "private method";
    }
}
```

I have got a private method that is used by my actual method and a protected single argumented constructor.

I need to write test case for my '`method1()`'.
I need to use junit and EasyMock.

Comment: what do you want to try to test here? What's the test case like?

Comment: Actually i want to test method1(),but how can i call that method in my testcase without creating the object of my class.i even cannot extend this class to write a mock class because it doesn't have a default constructor.
i want to test it like this,
assertEquals("method1 private method",objectOfActualclass.method1());

Comment: You can't. Its an abstract class. Btw JDK does provide default constructor to you if you dont have any constructor defined. You could mock it though but that doesnt help you. You might have concrete class. Call it using that?

Answer (score -1):

Test class is also a typical java class, it can extend other classes, even tested class, so you can do this:

```
class AbstractClassTest extends AbstractClass
{
    public AbstractClassTest()
    {
        super("some_string");
    } 
    @Test
    public void testMethod1()
    {
         //....
    }
}
```

Since test class is extending base class you have to call in it's constructor  the base class constructor. You don't have setter for this private field, so if you will need to test more instances you can instantiate test class inside test class:

```
AbstractClassTest abc = new AbstractClassTest("other_string");
```

To do this you will need second ctor for test class:

```
public AbstractClassTest(String param)
{
    super(param);
}
```

Comment: It is throwing an error if i did so...because the constructor in my class is PROTECTED.

Comment: `protected` means that it can be used by classes that extends abstract class and test class does it so error is caused by something else.

Comment: my IDE is not allowing me to extend that class,it is asking me to define an explicit constrcutor in my main class.

Comment: I had error in test class constructor name, if you fix it it should be ok

Comment: Also I just did it with Java 7 on netbeans 8 and there was no problem

Answer (score -1):

I would test it using concrete class implementation like:

```
 MyConcreteClass clazz = ..;//MyConcreteClass could be local class or actual production class
 Assert.assertEquals("method1 private method",clazz.method1());
```